# Select group by with a max predicate

Tags: sql, sql-server

Quite often I have to do queries like below:

```
select    col1, max(id)
from      Table
where     col2 = 'value'
and       col3 = (    select    max(col3)
                      from      Table
                      where     col2 = 'value'
                 )
group by col1
```

Are there any other ways to avoid subqueries and temp tables? Basically I need a `group by` on all the rows with a particular max value. Assuming all proper indices are used.

Comment: There isn't really anything wrong the subquery you are using, because it is not correlated to the outer query.  While you might be able to rewrite your query, I would probably just leave it as is.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an OLAP function to achieve this. I would say this solution is marginally better in that your predicates are not duplicated between the main query and subquery, so you don't violate [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself):

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    select    col1, max(id) as max_id,
              RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY col1 ORDER BY col3 DESC) AS irow
    from      [Member]
    where     col2 = 'value'
    group by  col1
) subquery
WHERE subquery.irow = 1
```